# Creating PDF File with Princexml

Tags: php, pdf, princexml

I want to convert a table from my php page into pdf.. I pass it through a form element and retrieve on other page.
I tried using many pdf convertor like fpdf, dompdf and other but sadly  none worked.
Always had some errors. I also came across through mpdf it worked fine but had to ask the client to manually save the pdf.

I tried using princexml using phpwrapper file (prince.php). But i am getting 
    deprecated error.![][1]

The code i used is as follows

```
<body>
<?php 
include "prince.php";
$prince = new Prince('../../../Program Files (x86)/Prince/Engine/bin/prince.exe');
$prince->convert_file_to_file("license.txt","license.pdf",'inf');
$msg=array("hey","hello");
echo $prince->convert_string_to_file("Rahul","rahul.pdf",$msg[]);
?>
</body>`
```

I want echo $prince->convert_string_to_file("Rahul","rahul.pdf",$msg[]); to work.
Pls help... stuck at it for a long time!!!

Comment: Which command is deprecated?

Comment: The third parameter that i am sending in $prince->convert_string_to_file("Rahul","rahul.pdf",$msg[]);